# DataTables form with checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, datatable

I'm trying to create DataTable in CodeIgniter with data from MySql. I'm not sure how to create form on DataTable that will handle checkboxes on each row.

HTML

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Discount</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Discount</th>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach($data as $d): ?>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><?=$d->name?></td>
            <td><?=$d->price?></td>
            <td><?=$d->discount?>%</td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading datatable's documentation. You'll find it there.

Comment: I already tried that but I don't know how to integrate it with MySql data and foreach loop.

Comment: The answer will be too long for stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you know some useful link?